# Google Chart to draw linechart

Tags: c#, json, google-visualization, linechart

I managed to get dataset for drawing my chart as per my requirement like this:

[image]

Now I want to pass this to my google charts api to draw line chart.

I have done pivoting on my table for getting the desired dataset. Here in this example column1 has months and rest columns are actually from the database(so not sure how many more columns will be there).

I want json string of this format:

```
"{\"cols\":[
{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Month\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"},
{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Col1\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"},
{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Col2\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"},
{\"id\":\"\",\"label\":\"Col3\",\"pattern\":\"\",\"type\":\"number\"}
],
\"rows\":[
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Jan\"},{\"v\":37.8},{\"v\":80.8},{\"v\":41.8}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Feb\"},{\"v\":30.9},{\"v\":69.5},{\"v\":32.4}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Mar\"},{\"v\":25.4},{\"v\":57},{\"v\":25.7}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Apr\"},{\"v\":11.7},{\"v\":18.8},{\"v\":10.5}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"May\"},{\"v\":11.9},{\"v\":17.6},{\"v\":10.4}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Jun\"},{\"v\":8.8},{\"v\":13.6},{\"v\":7.7}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Jul\"},{\"v\":7.6},{\"v\":12.3},{\"v\":9.6}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Aug\"},{\"v\":12.3},{\"v\":29.2},{\"v\":10.6}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Sep\"},{\"v\":16.9},{\"v\":42.9},{\"v\":14.8}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Oct\"},{\"v\":12.8},{\"v\":30.9},{\"v\":11.6}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Nov\"},{\"v\":5.3},{\"v\":7.9},{\"v\":4.7}]},
{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"Dec\"},{\"v\":6.6},{\"v\":8.4},{\"v\":5.2}]}]}"
```

How can I form my object class to return this json string? Any ideas would be helpful.

The last option I can think of is building my json string dynamically using stringBuilder. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: just google for serialization json, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you need to serialize a server object into json format ? if that's what you need, try Newtonsoft. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: My main concern here is I can not serialize it directly as I don't know how many columns will be there. In my example I have month, col1, col2, col3.. But there can be more.. Since I have done pivot, I am not sure how many more more columns will be there. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work, This is how I serialized my Json object:

```
 public class Col
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string pattern { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        public object v { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public List<C> c { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Col> cols { get; set; }
        public List<Row> rows { get; set; }
    }
```